# javascript function to get random array items where sum matches amount

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

This is a super odd question... but I have an array of currency:

```
var currency = [
{label: "penny", value: 0.01},
label: "nickel", value: 0.05}, 
label: "dime", value: 0.10}].. etc..
}
```

and a var price = 2.15

I'm trying to make an algorithm that randomly generates 5-10 coins from the array... such that there is always the ability to make the price... but say, 4 extra "garbage" coins.

But even the coins used to solve the equation should be random. IE. if its $0.20, I don't want the answer to always have $0.05, $0.05, $0.05 $0.05... maybe one possibility is just $0.10, $0.10...

It returns an array of the all the "Random" coins so I can place them on the page.

I'm working on this and thought it might something fun for others to try too.

Comment: What do you mean by 4 extra "garbage" coins?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one "random" way . Just iterates until random coins are found, each time you click there's a good chance you will have totally different coins.

```js
const currency = [{
    label: "penny",
    value: 0.01
  },
  {
    label: "nickel",
    value: 0.05
  },
  {
    label: "dime",
    value: 0.10
  },
  {
    label: "quarter",
    value: 0.25
  }
];

function getCoins(value) {
  const coinsUsed = [];
  let currentValue = value;

  while (currentValue > 0) {
    const coin = randomCoin(currentValue);
    coinsUsed.push(coin);
    currentValue -= coin.value;
    currentValue = currentValue.toFixed(2);
  }

  display(coinsUsed);
}

function randomCoin(value) {
  let coin = 0;
  do {
    coin = currency[~~(Math.random() * currency.length)];
  }
  while (coin.value > value);
  return coin;
}

function display(coinsUsed) {
  // display.
  const pennies = coinsUsed.filter(el => el.label === 'penny').length;
  const nickels = coinsUsed.filter(el => el.label === 'nickel').length;
  const dimes = coinsUsed.filter(el => el.label === 'dime').length;
  const quarters = coinsUsed.filter(el => el.label === 'quarter').length;

  document.querySelector('.pennies').textContent = `${pennies}x Pennies`;
  document.querySelector('.nickels').textContent = `${nickels}x Nickels`
  document.querySelector('.dimes').textContent = `${dimes}x Dimes`
  document.querySelector('.quarters').textContent = `${quarters}x Quarters`

  const total = coinsUsed.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc + cur.value
  }, 0);

  document.querySelector('.total').textContent = `${total.toFixed(2)} Total`
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getCoins(parseFloat(input.value));
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Get Coins</button>
<ul>
  <li class='pennies'></li>
  <li class='nickels'></li>
  <li class='dimes'></li>
  <li class='quarters'></li>
  <li class='total'></li>
</ul>
```